# How do we find the symmetry group of a differential equations?

Tags: group-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In physics, one very important principle is to see which transformations an equation is invariant in. For example, the Maxwell's equation are invariant under Lorentz transformations, Newton's second law under Galilean and so on. My question is, how can one, given a differential equation, systematically find it's symmetry group?

Comment: Here is an article from the historical perspective with examples:
https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/when-lie-groups-became-physics/

Comment: The answer is much too long to be written here! See some textbook, like Olver's [Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations](https://www.amazon.com/Applications-Differential-Equations-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387950001), for instance.